# Java Class Renaming in Bytecode Representation

Tags: java, class, rename, bytecode, instrumentation

Given a `byte[]` array for a *.class* file: is it possible to rename all class references for a given class inside the bytecode? (E.g. from *test.class* -> *test_new_version.class* including all the constructors or any other bytecode references). If so, what is a good library to achieve this?

Comment: you can do this using the ASM library.

Comment: It's theoretically possible to create a class that can't be renamed due to classfile limits. But this is something you'll never see in practice. ASM is probably the most popular library for this.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: actually, ASM is very bad for this job. Renaming a class reference using ASM implies traversing all fields, methods, annotations, etc and repeat the replace operation for every bytecode artifact referring to the class, whereas usually there’s only one name reference and one occurrence per distinct signature to be replaced in the constant pool which could be processed without looking at the rest of the class.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly possible using the ASM library. The FAQ for this library even gives an [example for how to rename a class in its tutorial](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/faq.html#Q6).

Effectively, you need to use a `RemappingClassAdapter` that comes with the library's utilities. To generate legal byte code, the renamed class must be fully binary compatible to the replaced class.